# How do I get the class instance ID in Swift?

Tags: swift

In Objective-C, I would use the following code to identify an instance of a class and the function being called in the console.

```
NSLog(@"[DMLOG - %@] %@", NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), self);
```

This would return something like the console out below, where I would get an instance ID to track different instances of an object.

```
[DMLOG - prepForInput] <GridBase: 0x7fb71860a190>
```

How can I get both the instance ID and the function being called within Swift? I've tried the following to get the ID in Swift but it only provides the class name and no instance ID value? Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
print("[DBG] Init: \(self)")
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To get current function name use `#function` literal.

As for instance ID, looks like you have two options:

1. Inherit from `NSObject` (UIKit classes inherit it anyways) so that class instances would have instance IDs:

   ```
   class MyClass: NSObject {
     override init() {
       super.init()
       print("[DBG: \(#function)]: \(self)")
     }
   }
   ```
2. If your class does not inherit from `NSObject` you can still identify your instances by memory address:

   ```
   class Jumbo {
     init() {
       print("[DBG: \(#function)]: \(Unmanaged.passUnretained(self).toOpaque())")
     }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks Dan! This works great on all classes! I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran a quick test using the following:

```
print("\(self) \(#function) - Count \(count)")
```

I got the following result:

```
<XXXXXXX.FeedViewController: 0x7fcebdf05d40> viewWillAppear - Count 3
```

I would give that a try and see if it helps.

Comment: Just checked this out and it appears to give an instance ID only if it is the ViewController but not any other class. Really odd as it will show if I subclass an NSObject but that isn't recommended so still need to figure out a way to get the ID if any class other than a VC or NSObject.

Comment: Ah, sorry I missed that.  Didn't think to try that.